# Find median for each element in list

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have some large list of data, between 1000 and 10000 elements. Now I want to filter out some peak values with the help of the median function.

```
    #example list with just 10 elements
    my_list = [4.5, 4.7, 5.1, 3.9, 9.9, 5.6, 4.3, 0.2, 5.0, 4.6]
    
    #list of medians calculated from 3 elements
    my_median_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i == 0:
            my_median_list.append(statistics.median([my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2]])
        elif i == (len(my_list)-1):
            my_median_list.append(statistics.median([my_list[-1], my_list[-2], my_list[-3]])
        else:
            my_median_list.append(statistics.median([my_list[i-1], my_list[i], my_list[i+1]])

    print(my_median_list)
    # [4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 5.1, 5.6, 5.6, 4.3, 4.3, 4.6, 4.6]
```

This works so far. But I think it looks ugly and is maybe inefficient? Is there a way with statistics or NumPy to do it faster? Or another solution? Also, I look for a solution where I can pass an argument from how many elements the median is calculated. In my example, I used the median always from 3 elements. But with my real data, I want to play with the median setting and then maybe use the median out of 10 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating too many values since:

```
my_median_list.append(statistics.median([my_list[i-1], my_list[i], my_list[i+1]])
```

and

```
my_median_list.append(statistics.median([my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2]])
```

are the same when `i == 1`. The same error happens at the end so you get one too many end values.

It's easier and less error-prone to do this with `zip()` which will make the three element tuples for you:

```
from statistics import median

my_list = [4.5, 4.7, 5.1, 3.9, 9.9, 5.6, 4.3, 0.2, 5.0, 4.6]

[median(l) for l in zip(my_list, my_list[1:], my_list[2:])]
# [4.7, 4.7, 5.1, 5.6, 5.6, 4.3, 4.3, 4.6]
```

For groups of arbitrary size [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is super handy because you can set a max size. Then you just keep pushing items on one end and it removes items off the other to maintain the size. Here's a generator example that takes you groups size as `n`:

```
from statistics import median
from collections import deque

def rolling_median(l, n):
    d = deque(l[0:n], n)
    yield median(d)
    for num in l[n:]:
        d.append(num)
        yield median(d)
    
my_list = [4.5, 4.7, 5.1, 3.9, 9.9, 5.6, 4.3, 0.2, 5.0, 4.6]

list(rolling_median(my_list, 3))
# [4.7, 4.7, 5.1, 5.6, 5.6, 4.3, 4.3, 4.6]

list(rolling_median(my_list, 5))
# [4.7, 5.1, 5.1, 4.3, 5.0, 4.6]
```

Comment: You are right I calculated to many values... with the rolling_median function my task is a lot easier, thank you!